# buffer overflow Identification in the code

Tags: c

Is the following code  vulnerable to buffer over flow attack. Please identify which line or lines of code are erroneous. Please suggest how to fix the vulnerability.

```
#include stdio.h

void manipulate(char *buffer) {
  char newbuffer[80];
  strcpy(newbuffer,buffer);
}

int main() {
  char ch,buffer[4096];
  int i=0;

  while ((buffer[i++] = getchar()) != '\n') {};

  i=1;
  manipulate(buffer);
  i=2;
  printf("The value of i is : %d\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like real code to me, but just to be someone dumping his homework on us.

Comment: home assignment on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1. while ((buffer[i++] = getchar()) != '\n')
```

You have to be sure that the number of characters being entered is less than 4096. Else you have a buffer overflow. While reading until the end of the line it would be better to use `fgets()` which is much safer.

```
2. strcpy(newbuffer,buffer);
```

What if your array `buffer` is filled then you have a buffer overflow because `newbuffer` can't hold 4096.Use some safer function here also in order to handle buffer overflow like `snprintf()`

Comment: @sami Does this answer your question? If so then accept this as answer right way to thank on SO

Answer (score 0):

Use strncpy() function instead. 
also while loop should not be iterated more than the length of "buffer"